# javascript function not returning value for a particular case

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a sample script in php and validation are done using javascript. I am generating a inputbox using ajax script on click of a button. When I click submit it checks whether all the boxes are filled or not.
  I am validating the boxes using for loop. When the boxes are empty it correctly alerts and I am returning false for the same case. But the problem is when all the boxes are filled it doesn't not return any thing and the function stops working even when I m returning true for this condition.
My javascript  code with function is shown below

```
function addInput(){
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var result = xmlhttp.responseText;


     var newElem = document.createElement ("div");
            newElem.innerHTML = result;
     newElem.id = "input";

       var container = document.getElementById ("main");
            container.appendChild (newElem);

    }

  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

var count = '<?php echo $_SESSION['z']; ?>'

function check(){
    function validate()
    {   
        for(var i=1; i<=count+10; i++)
        {
            if(document.getElementById("text"+i+"").value == "")
            {
                alert("Please Enter Start Date For Sales Promotion");
                document.getElementById("text"+i+"").focus();
                return 'false';
            }
        }
        return 'abc';
    }

    var flag = validate();
    if(flag != 'false')
    {
        alert("correct");
    }
}
```

MY html code is shown below

```
<form method="post" action="save.php">
<div id="main">
    <div id="input1">
            Enter Name </br></br>
            <input type="text" id="text1" />
            <?php $_SESSION['z'] = 2; ?>
    </div>
</div>
</br>
<input type="button" value="add another" onclick="addInput()" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="check()" />
</form>
<div id="display"></div>
```

my ajax code is shown below

```
 <?php
session_start();
$q = $_SESSION['z'];

?>

            Enter Name </br></br>
            <input type="text" id="text<?php echo $q; ?>" />

<?php $q = $q + 1; 
$_SESSION['z'] = $q;

?>
```

the problem is when all the fields are filled it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console to see if the JS is breaking and throwing an error?

Comment: Why do you implement AJAX XMLHttpRequest creation etc all by yourself? If you used a library like JQuery to do that, your code will be much simpler, and less error prone.

Comment: @BuddhiP Maybe he doesn't need to have all the users download 40kb of library code for a simple request. Besides, that doesn't look like the problem anyway.

Comment: @BuddhiP , Actually for such a simple code i don't want to have much pains... ;-)
Problem is different. Please try to run that code if u can get any solution.... And thanks for rply...

Comment: @ZebRawnsley : how would I do that???

Comment: @JeffreySweeney, may be you are right. But I do not think he is worried about negligible performance hit of including jQuery, to me it looks more like not being aware of 'better way's (at least in my opinion) to do things, that's why thought of hint him of that. (DISCLAIMER: I do not get any profit by promoting jQuery, but I just like people not to re-invent the wheel) :)

Answer (score 0):

This may occur a lot, and according to the browser used, the click event and submit event will be call at the same time, it's not safe (for exemple, in IE if your submit button call another submit function, the form will be submitted twice...)

You should wire your check function to the onBeforeSubmit event of your form.

Comment: @samsherHell: I have not used the submit event. So I think that should n't be the problem. 
Than also can u tell me how to wire check funtion to the onbeforesubmit event.

Sorry for such idiotic questions.
and thanks for the rply......

Comment: submit event happen whenever you click a submit button in a form. I suggest you to use a javascript framework to make it more easy to code, in theorie it would be : document.form_name.onbeforesubmit = function() { check();}; if you need to prevent submitting on error, your check function or the beforesubmit event need to stop events propagation (beforesubmit -> submit)

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you get an error when you try to retrieve an item which does not exist on the page.

```
            if(document.getElementById("text"+i+"").value == "")
            {
                alert("Please Enter Start Date For Sales Promotion");
                document.getElementById("text"+i+"").focus();
                return 'false';
            }
```

Here may be there are no items with ids like "text8", "text9", etc. In that case there will be null reference error when you try to get value of non exisisting element.

Try changing it like this:

```
            var ele = document.getElementById("text"+i); 
            if(ele && ele.value == "")
            {
                alert("Please Enter Start Date For Sales Promotion");
                document.getElementById("text"+i+"").focus();
                return 'false';
            }
```

This validates if `ele` is null or not before accessing the value of it.

Comment: @BhddhiP: Thanks a lot sir......
your code worked. I think adding value in counter was the problem.